# Error spring mvc, hibernate project(when submitting a form)

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I got this error when I submit the register form. Function is adding users into the database.

```
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for                                      HTTP request with URI [/NumRemembering/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring-dispatcher'
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/NumRemembering/register] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring-dispatcher'
```

This is web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com /xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>NumberRemembering</display-name>
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

This is the spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


<context:component-scan base-package="com.controller"/>



<bean id="viewResolver"
     class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix">
    <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
</property> 
<property name="suffix">
    <value>.jsp</value>
</property>

 </bean>
 <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
 <mvc:annotation-driven />
 </beans>
```

This is hibernate.cfg.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/remember_me</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">Uthpala@123</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>      
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <mapping class="main.java.com.beans.User" />
</session-factory>
```

This is the part of the Login.jsp file

```
        <form action="register" method="post" commandName="user">
                                            <!-- <div class="form-sub-w3ls">
                                                <input placeholder="User Name"  type="text" required="">
                                                <div class="icon-agile">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                                </div>
                                            </div> -->
                                            <div class="form-sub-w3ls">
                                                <input placeholder="Email/Username" class="mail" type="email" required="">
                                                <div class="icon-agile">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-sub-w3ls">
                                                <input placeholder="Password"  type="password" required="">
                                                <div class="icon-agile">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-unlock-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-sub-w3ls">
                                                <input placeholder="Confirm Password"  type="password" required="">
                                                <div class="icon-agile">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-unlock-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- <div class="login-check">
                                         <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" checked=""><p>I Accept Terms & Conditions</p></label>
                                        </div> -->
                                    <div class="submit-w3l">
                                        <input type="submit" value="Register">
                                    </div>
                                    </form>
```

This is the UserController.java class

```
package main.java.com.controller;

import java.util.Map;

import main.java.com.beans.User;
import main.java.com.service.UserService;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
@Controller
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @RequestMapping(value="/register", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addUser(@ModelAttribute User user, BindingResult result,    @RequestParam String action, Map<String, Object> map){
    //User userResult = new User();
    userService.add(user);
    //userResult = user;
    //map.put("user", userResult);
    return "success";
     }
}
```

I have tried so many ways to solve this problem but could not resolve it. Its really great if someone can help me. Thank you in advance

Comment: Also add your web.xml, above all the part where you defined the dispatcher mapping

Comment: @akuma8 web.xml is added

Answer (score 0):

I could not see where you have mapped "NumRemembering".. You have mapped "/register" path in controller to "addUser" not "/NumRemembering/register".

Check your URL mapping in the spring controller.

Comment: Even after changing the url mapping in the controller I am still getting the same error. Any other solution or do you need more files me to upload?

Comment: @UthpalaPitawela hope you would have fixed that issue. If not , what's the URL you have mapped now ?

Answer (score 0):

```
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/NumRemembering/register] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring-dispatcher'
```

That means you have not well mapped your URL to your handler method. 2 ways to solve this :

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/NumRemembering/register", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addUser(@ModelAttribute User user, BindingResult result,    @RequestParam String action, Map<String, Object> map){
     userService.add(user);
     return "success";
   }
}
```

Or

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/NumRemembering/")
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping(value="register", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addUser(@ModelAttribute User user, BindingResult result,    @RequestParam String action, Map<String, Object> map){
     userService.add(user);
     return "success";
   }
}
```

Or **EDIT2**

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/register" method="post" commandName="user">
```

Comment: After changing the url still I am getting the same error. Do I need to do any change in spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml??

Comment: What is your application context? The root of your app.

Comment: its NumRemembering

Comment: See EDIT2 and in your controller keep your first version !

Comment: Got this error!!!!    WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/NumRemembering/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring-dispatcher'
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/NumRemembering/register] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring-dispatcher'

Comment: Edit and add your servlet config.

Comment: dispatcher-servlet is attached above. Its too long to add as a comment.